# Should I apply for grad school at higher-ranked institutions besides the one I am working at now?

Tags: phd

I am trying to decide about my future and it does look like a dilemma to me for the following reason: I can probably get accepted to PhD program in a good university in europe (top 30 in the subject, top 20 in general) to work with a professional supervisor that I had an experience working with and we were happy to work together. However, friends here tell me that my resume is better than the overall student in the university and I have the chance to get an admission from top 10’s. As I am conservative, I do not want to take a risk. I want to be sure if I can get admitted to PhD programs in top 10 after starting a PhD program if I did not find the university satisfying to me. I am an undergrad student.

Comment: I don’t understand why you would not apply to both.

Comment: @Dawn it’s complicated but if I apply to top 10 universities, then I will lose this chance and vice versa. So I have to choose only one

Comment: @mathvc_ I don't understand. Why can you only apply to one? It seems to me that you should apply to lots of PhD programs and then decide once you get multiple offers. This is what most people do.

Comment: @Thomas because I have to contact directly the supervisor and if I tell them that I wanna be their student, then I cannot choose between multiple offers! Moreover, I need their recommendation letter for other universities. It’s all about taking risk. Does it make sense?

Comment: @mathvc_ Please edit your question to make the dilemma clear. I do not follow your concern.

Comment: I tried to clarify the title closer to what you are actually asking, because I thought the original title suggested that you were talking about *switching to another school while already a PhD student* whereas the body of your question makes clear that is not the case. Please edit it if I have gotten your meaning wrong.

Comment: _I have to contact directly the supervisor and if I tell them that I wanna be their student_ — No, you have to contact potential supervisors and tell them that _if you are admitted_ then you would be interested in being their student.  You cannot be expected to make a commitment before even knowing what your options are.

Answer (score 5):

**You should apply to programs you are interested in working in, regardless of their ranking.**

If you are worried about upsetting your current supervisor by letting them know you might be interested in working elsewhere, consider this: *If your supervisor won't allow you to apply to other programs they are a jerk who doesn't have your best interests in mind, and you should work with someone else.*

**A good advisor will write you recommendation letters for any program you are interested in and let you make the decision, because it's your decision, not theirs.** They are free to be disappointed if you decide to go elsewhere because they value your contributions to their lab, but they are abusive if they threaten to withhold recommendations to keep you in place. *If you trust your current advisor enough to work with them in the future as a graduate student, you should also expect that they will be willing to write recommendations for you for any programs you are interested in.*

That said, it would be both impolite and misguided for you to rank the opportunities ahead of time. You should not attend an institution just because it is "top XX" on some measure of rankings: you should attend the institution where you are most likely to learn and produce good work. A key element of that is the selection of your advisor. Working with a helpful advisor who has your best interests in mind is going to be a far better learning experience for you, regardless of "rank" of the institution.

Comment: Yes! Every good advisor will recommend going to the program where you will have the best learning, most resources, and best chance of meeting your career goals. We want you to succeed!